# How to calculate the amout of time for oil to get out from a pneumatic cylinder?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, pressure

I have a system. You can assume it is just a 1" diameter steel pneumatic cylinder (1 foot long). Assume we ignore the bore size issue at this point. One chamber is filled up by oil (6" of volume), this chamber also has a hole to let the oil to go to atmosphere. The other half is connected to a 'x' psi gas pressure source (let x = 20 at this time).

My question is how to calculate the amount of time does the system take for all oil to get out from the cylinder?

Please give me some direction

Thanks

Comment: Look for "flow through orifice" for the equations.

Comment: Related link: http://www.efunda.com/formulae/fluids/draining_tank.cfm

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the system is horizontal, write the Bernouilly equation between the piston and the bore hole. From it you get V. Then write the equation for the volume remaining inside:
Vol(t)=Vol(0)-V*s*t
Where s is the surface of the bore.